# SQL CASE when value equals zero, return value from another row with identical values

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am writing a SQL query that returns part numbers, job operations and the time it takes to complete each operation.

The times are entered from a front end ERP system.

Sometimes the job operation times are left blank by mistake, this results in a time of 0 (zero) being entered in the table.

I would like to populate the time value if it is zero with a time from a another row, where the job operation and part number is the same as the current row and the time value is not zero also.

If no value other than zero is found then just use zero.

```
SELECT 
    B.[PartNo] AS [Part],
    A.[JobOpNo] AS [Operation],
    A.[JobAllocatedTime] AS [ALLOCATED TIME],
    -- (CASE 
    --     WHEN A.[JobAllocatedTime] = 0 THEN (SELECT [JobAllocatedTime] FROM [JobOperations] WHERE (the Part & Operation are the same as this rows Part & Operation AND the Allocated Time is Not = 0 , if no number other than zero is found the use 0) 
    --     ELSE A.[JobAllocatedTime] END) AS [ALLOCATED TIME] 
FROM 
    [JobOperations] A
JOIN
    [JobOrders] B ON A.[JobOpOrderNo] = B.[OrderNo]
ORDER BY 
    A.[JobOpOrderNo] DESC
```

I have a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51936/2) here.

The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2017

I can achieve this using a stored procedure, however, I am wondering if there is a more basic way of achieving this, possibly using a built in command / function.

Comment: And what if there is more than one matching value?

Comment: @marc_s - I will edit the question. It must be SQL Server 2017, with SQL Management Studio 2018 - It's hard to keep track of Microsoft!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I was hoping that's where the expert suggestions would come in - I imagine the largest number returned would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT jo.PartNo AS [Part],
       jop.JobOpNo AS [Operation],
       (CASE WHEN jop.JobAllocatedTime = 0
             THEN MAX(jop.JobAllocatedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY jo.PartNo, jop.JobOpNo)
             ELSE jop.JobAllocatedTime 
        END) AS [ALLOCATED TIME]
FROM JobOperations jop JOIN
     JobOrders jo
     ON jop.[JobOpOrderNo] = jo.[OrderNo]    
     ORDER BY 1, 2
ORDER BY jop.[JobOpOrderNo] DESC;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e6bd8e9471ef57b82d7218bbbed701f) is a db<>fiddle.

This calculates the maximum value according to your conditions and replaces `0` values with that value.

Comment: This seems to work a treat - running some tests on a larger datatset